# Drawing 9 draws from 1 bag containing 2 colors; probability of getting at least 7 balls of same color.

Tags: probability

A bag contains $90$ balls, of which $50$ balls are red [P(r)=5/9], and $40$ balls are blue [P(b)=4/9].

We are given $9$ attempts to draw a ball from this bag randomly, after each attempt, the drawn ball would be kept aside, out of the bag [without replacement].

What is the probability that **at least** $7$ of the balls drawn, would be of **same color**?

**EDIT:**

***Possible solution***

excatly 7 red balls:
$\frac{{K\choose k}{\cdot}{N-K\choose n-k}}{N\choose n}$
${\tiny\begin{array}{ll}N &=90 \\ K &=50 \\ n &=9 \\ k &=7 \end{array}}$
$\frac{{50\choose 7}{\cdot}{40\choose 2}}{90\choose 9}$

excatly 8 red balls:
$\frac{{K\choose k}{\cdot}{N-K\choose n-k}}{N\choose n}$
${\tiny\begin{array}{ll}N &=90 \\ K &=50 \\ n &=9 \\ k &=8 \end{array}}$
$\frac{{50\choose 8}{\cdot}{40\choose 1}}{90\choose 9}$

excatly 9 red balls:
$\frac{{K\choose k}{\cdot}{N-K\choose n-k}}{N\choose n}$
${\tiny\begin{array}{ll}N &=90 \\ K &=50 \\ n &=9 \\ k &=9 \end{array}}$
$\frac{{50\choose 9}{\cdot}{40\choose 0}}{90\choose 9}$

excatly 7 blue balls:
$\frac{{K\choose k}{\cdot}{N-K\choose n-k}}{N\choose n}$
${\tiny\begin{array}{ll}N &=90 \\ K &=40 \\ n &=9 \\ k &=7 \end{array}}$
$\frac{{40\choose 7}{\cdot}{50\choose 2}}{90\choose 9}$

excatly 8 blue balls:
$\frac{{K\choose k}{\cdot}{N-K\choose n-k}}{N\choose n}$
${\tiny\begin{array}{ll}N &=90 \\ K &=40 \\ n &=9 \\ k &=8 \end{array}}$
$\frac{{40\choose 8}{\cdot}{50\choose 1}}{90\choose 9}$

excatly 9 blue balls:
$\frac{{K\choose k}{\cdot}{N-K\choose n-k}}{N\choose n}$
${\tiny\begin{array}{ll}N &=90 \\ K &=40 \\ n &=9 \\ k &=9 \end{array}}$
$\frac{{40\choose 9}{\cdot}{50\choose 0}}{90\choose 9}$

$\frac{{50\choose 7}{\cdot}{40\choose 2}}{90\choose 9}$
$+$
$\frac{{50\choose 8}{\cdot}{40\choose 1}}{90\choose 9}$
$+$
$\frac{{50\choose 9}{\cdot}{40\choose 0}}{90\choose 9}$
$+$
$\frac{{40\choose 7}{\cdot}{50\choose 2}}{90\choose 9}$
$+$
$\frac{{40\choose 8}{\cdot}{50\choose 1}}{90\choose 9}$
$+$
$\frac{{40\choose 9}{\cdot}{50\choose 0}}{90\choose 9}$

$=$
$\frac{\left({\frac{50!}{7!{\cdot}(50-7)!}}\right){\cdot}\left({\frac{40!}{2!{\cdot}(40-2)!}}\right)}{\left({\frac{90!}{9!{\cdot}(90-81)!}}\right)}$
$+$
$\frac{\left({\frac{50!}{8!{\cdot}(50-8)!}}\right){\cdot}\left({\frac{40!}{1!{\cdot}(40-1)!}}\right)}{\left({\frac{90!}{9!{\cdot}(90-81)!}}\right)}$
$+$
$\frac{\left({\frac{50!}{9!{\cdot}(50-9)!}}\right){\cdot}\left({\frac{40!}{0!{\cdot}(40-0)!}}\right)}{\left({\frac{90!}{9!{\cdot}(90-81)!}}\right)}$

$+$
$\frac{\left({\frac{40!}{7!{\cdot}(40-7)!}}\right){\cdot}\left({\frac{50!}{2!{\cdot}(50-2)!}}\right)}{\left({\frac{90!}{9!{\cdot}(90-81)!}}\right)}$
$+$
$\frac{\left({\frac{40!}{8!{\cdot}(40-8)!}}\right){\cdot}\left({\frac{50!}{1!{\cdot}(50-1)!}}\right)}{\left({\frac{90!}{9!{\cdot}(90-81)!}}\right)}$
$+$
$\frac{\left({\frac{40!}{9!{\cdot}(40-9)!}}\right){\cdot}\left({\frac{50!}{0!{\cdot}(50-0)!}}\right)}{\left({\frac{90!}{9!{\cdot}(90-81)!}}\right)}$

$=$
$\frac{708271200}{6420477533}$
$+$
$\frac{4540200}{149313431}$
$+$
$\frac{529690}{149313431}$
$+$
$\frac{134343300}{4154426639}$
$+$
$\frac{2056275}{377675149}$
$+$
$\frac{146224}{377675149}$

$=$
$\frac{314262063}{1722567143}$
$\approx$
${0.18244}$

Comment: @AnuragA that is a bad way of thinking of it in my opinion.  Remember that these balls are drawn without replacement, not with replacement.  Your suggestion would have been more helpful for the *with* replacement problem.  For the without replacement problem, it is much cleaner to treat the order in which the balls were drawn as irrelevant.

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree, I didn't read the question carefully. My mistake. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. 
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem? If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers. By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [ask], on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Drawing at least 7 balls of the same color would be equivalent to drawing $7$ red balls and two blue, drawing $8$ red balls and one blue, drawing $9$ red balls and zero blue, or the related outcomes having $7$ blue and two red, $8$ blue and one red, or $9$ blue and zero red.

It might save you some effort by looking at the opposite event then instead, corresponding to $(3,6),(4,5),(5,4),(6,3)$ red and blue balls respectively, but in either case approaching directly like this is going to take a little bit of effort.

Now... imagine that each ball is uniquely labeled.  For one of those specific cases, **choose** which red balls specifically were drawn as well as **choose** which blue balls were specifically drawn.

For additional reading and the correct search term, see [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).